# Pass two lines of text into InputBox

Tags: vbscript

I have the following line in my code asking for user input.

```
strFind = InputBox("Please enter the text to look for.","Replace Text in Files")
```

I need the user to input two lines of text separated by LF or CR or CRLF (line-breaks)
However the InputBox only excepts one line of text.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you create your own dialog?

Comment: @DanielA.White Its not for a webpage and not for HTA. its for plain .vbs file

Comment: you could create a custom one that uses com.

Comment: @DanielA.White any reference (link) to more info on this?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_userinput.php) for instance. Replace the `<input type="text">` with a `<textarea>` for multiline text.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Tried, Comes up with errors. Also I would prefer something more native to .VBS Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
dim completed

msgbox inputboxml("Enter text:", "Multiline inputbox via HTA", "default" & vbcrlf & vbtab & "multiline" & vbcrlf & "text")

function inputboxml(prompt, title, defval)
    dim window
    set window = createwindow()
    completed = 0
    defval = replace(replace(replace(defval, "&", "&amp;"), "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&gt;")
    with window
        with .document
            .title = title
            .body.style.background = "buttonface"
            .body.style.fontfamily = "consolas, courier new"
            .body.style.fontsize = "8pt"
            .body.innerhtml = "<div><center><nobr>" & prompt & "</nobr><br><br></center><textarea id='hta_textarea' style='font-family: consolas, courier new; width: 100%; height: 580px;'>" & defval & "</textarea><br><button id='hta_cancel' style='font-family: consolas, courier new; width: 85px; margin: 10px; padding: 3px; float: right;'>Cancel</button><button id='hta_ok' style='font-family: consolas, courier new; width: 85px; margin: 10px; padding: 3px; float: right;'>OK</button></div>"
        end with
        .resizeto 700, 700
        .moveto 100, 100
    end with
    window.hta_textarea.focus
    set window.hta_cancel.onclick = getref("hta_cancel")
    set window.hta_ok.onclick = getref("hta_ok")
    set window.document.body.onunload = getref("hta_onunload")
    do until completed > 0
        wscript.sleep 10
    loop
    select case completed
    case 1
        inputboxml = ""
    case 2
        inputboxml = ""
        window.close
    case 3
        inputboxml = window.hta_textarea.value
        window.close
    end select
end function

function createwindow()
    rem source http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=75356#p75356
    dim signature, shellwnd, proc
    on error resume next
    signature = left(createobject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").guid, 38)
    do
        set proc = createobject("WScript.Shell").exec("mshta ""about:<head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);</script><hta:application id=app border=dialog minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no scroll=no showintaskbar=yes contextmenu=no selection=yes innerborder=no icon=""%windir%\system32\notepad.exe""/><object id='shellwindow' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shellwindow.putproperty('" & signature & "',document.parentWindow);</script></head>""")
        do
            if proc.status > 0 then exit do
            for each shellwnd in createobject("Shell.Application").windows
                set createwindow = shellwnd.getproperty(signature)
                if err.number = 0 then exit function
                err.clear
            next
        loop
    loop
end function

sub hta_onunload
    completed = 1
end sub

sub hta_cancel
    completed = 2
end sub

sub hta_ok
    completed = 3
end sub
```